# Fit image inside a frame in a Blender model using python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, blender

I'm trying to update the content of an image in a GLB model imported by a Python script.

My script is importing the model and can replace any image without any issue, but the problem is in fitting this image within the frame.

#### More Details

we have a frame, and we need the new image to fill it in two modes

- to maximize the image **proportionally** to fill the entire space of the frame
- to minimize the image **proportionally** to be fitted inside the frame even if it doesn't fill the frame

The same way as Windows does when you add an image to a slide, for example, a prompt asks you to apply the image fitting of the two mentioned modes.

---

**My question is**: how can I apply that in Blender so that my function is expected to take the image_path (str) and fitting_mode (max/fit), you can see the `logo` image in the screenshot below

#### Notes:

- I'm calling Blender in the background using `subprocess` python module
- I tried with `node.projection = 'BOX'` Box or Flat but nothing is useful.
- I can't use PIL to do this as Blender can't find this module

All comments are appreciated

[image: fitting image inside a frame in Blender]